# Is there a proper way to map object key names to more readable representations?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

My server returns an object that looks like this:

```
{
   firstName: "Joe",
   lastName: "Smith",
   phoneNum: "212-222-2222"
}
```

I want to present this in the UI (built in Angular 2+) using `*ngFor` but I don't want to use the key names as they are now. I want something more user-friendly, like

```
First Name: Joe 
Last Name: Smith 
Phone Number: 212-222-2222
```

Is there a "proper" way to provide a mapping from key names to user-friendly key names? If not I would probably just do something to ensure key names as camel-cased and then in UI, use a function to convert camel case keynames to spaced user-friendly names.

But it would be cool if someone had a suggestion that didn't involve me changing anything on server side, and did a mapping on UI

Comment: Why not creating a prop name to display name mapping object on the UI ? I don't see anything wrong with that

Comment: That should be on presentation layer. You could leverage some lib like `ngx-translate` to translate key to text value.

Comment: Looks like you're not just converting case but also expanding abbreviated names like phoneNum to Phone Number.  I think the only way to do that is to have a clientside object or set of objects that provides the mapping like` { phoneNum : "Phone Number" }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expose an interface for a field mapper.

```
interface FieldMapper {
   firstName: string,
   lastName: string,
   phoneNumber: string,
}

interface LabeledField {
  label: string,
  value: string,
}

interface UserRenderable {
  firstname: LabeledField,
  lastname: LabeledField,
  phoneNumber: LabeledField,
}
```

Use this in your Component, e.g.

```
@Component({
    ...
    template: `
        <ul>
        <li *ngFor="#user of users">{{user.firstname.label}}
            {{user.firstname.value}}</li>
        <ul>
    `
})
export class Users {
    users: Array<UserRenderable>
    fieldMapper: FieldMapper = {
        firstName: 'First Name',
        lastName: 'Last Name',
        phoneNumber: 'Phone Number'
    }

    constructor(private userService : UserService) {
      const users = userService.get(); 
      this.users = users.map((u) => (
        Object.keys(
          this.fieldMapper
        )
        .reduce(
          (prev, currKey) => {
            prev[currKey] = {
              label: this.fieldMapper[k],
              value: u[k]
            }
            return prev;
          }, {})
      ));
    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a mapping of keys to readable labels and transform the response to objects with label/value.

These objects can be used in ngFor to display label and value.

```js
const response = {
   firstName: "Joe",
   lastName: "Smith",
   phoneNum: "212-222-2222"
};

const labels = {
   firstName: "First Name",
   lastName: "Last Name",
   phoneNum: "Phone Number",
   address: "Address"
}

const result = Object.keys(response).map(key => ({label: labels[key], value: response[key]}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, I would not say there is a correct way since keys can be fairly arbitrary.
Regardless, if you have a fixed set of keys, you can create a an object that maps to the user friendly property keys and reference it in your display logic.

For example:

```
export class Component {
  friendlyKeys = {
    firstName: "First Name",
    lastName: "Last Name",
    phoneNum: "Phone Number"
  };
}
```

and reference it from your template

```
<div *ngFor="property of properties">
  <div>
    {{friendlyKeys[property.key] || property.key}}: {{property.value}}
  </div>
</div>
```

The above code is a bit awkward since the fall back logic (`{{|| property.key}}`) is embedded in the view. If we had a more complex strategy, for example we might want to attempt a lookup in several mapping objects and fall-back to a strategy where we split up a key based on letter casing or something, it will quickly become unwieldy. We can move the logic into a function in order to make to keep the view itself free of logic. As a bonus this makes it easier to test the mapping behavior.

```
export class Component {
  friendlyKey = friendlyKey;
}

export const friendlyKeys = {
  firstName: "First Name",
  lastName: "Last Name",
  phoneNum: "Phone Number"
};

export function friendlyKey(key: string) {
  return friendlyKeys[key] || key;
}
```

Then we would reference it from out template

```
<div *ngFor="property of properties">
  <div>
    {{friendlyKey(property.key)}}: {{property.value}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Downvoter please comment on how you think this answer should be improved or what is wrong with it. I don't see how the approach is invalid at the very least. Besides, all of the other answers that actually can solve the issue use a similar approach. Of course if someone could use something more complicated and more general, but this isn't really a translation it's a transformation, and mapping through an object or function aligns with KISS.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use some kind of data binding, with some sort of labels in HTML?
I think the key names don't usually appear in your UI, your code should look something like:

```
<lable>First name</label>{{firstName}}
<lable>Last name</label>{{lastName}}
```

I can edit the code in the answer to give a more working example for angular2 but I think this is the way to do it, so I don't understand why you need to have user-friendly key names because the user doesn't even see them.

Edit:
my angular is rusty, however from this link:
[dislpalying data in angular](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data)
I can see that you should creat a template, and your template should contain the data, so the template should be something like:

```
template: `
<lable>firstName</lable>{{firstName}}
<label>lastName</lable>{{lastName}}
`
```

etc...

and you use your *ngFor on the template.

Edit2:
I'll provide you with a more working example specific to your case,
you should get from your server an array of objects not only one object or else you wouldn't need the ngfor, and you'll need to iterate on that object array, let's say your array was called `people` and you got it from an api call:
`let people = getPeople()`
and you'll need your template to create a custom tag `person`:

```
<Person *ngFor="let person of people">
  First Name:{{person.firstName}}
  Last Name:{{person.lastName}}
  Number: {{person.number}}
</person>
```

Comment: Yes but then I can't do this in an `*ngFor`

Comment: I think you should build a template and fill the data inside the template and use the ngFor on the template, I'll update my answer.

Comment: the main idea is that you don't show the key names, they are for you as developer to reach the data in the object.